# Image of a map $f : k^3 \longrightarrow k^3$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and define $f : k^3 \longrightarrow k^3$ by $$f(x,y,z) = (x, xy, xyz).$$

I would like to verify that the image of this map is $$f(k^3) = \{ (0,0,0) \} \cup k^3 \backslash \{ x,y =0 \},$$ where $f^{-1}(k^3 \backslash \{ x,y =0 \}) = k^3 \backslash \{ x,y =0 \}$ and $f^{-1}(\{ (0,0,0) \}) = \{ (0,0,z) : z \in k \}$.

Notice that (if my computation is correct) the image is neither open or closed in $k^3$. How does one determine if the image is dense?

Please note that $k^3 = \mathbb{A}_k^3$ equipped with the Zariski topology.

*Context*: qualifying exam preparation.

Comment: I think there are quite a few funny things going on here. But for one your preimage of the origin cannot be correct for $f(0,1,1)=(0,0,0)$. In fact, fix $x=0$ and then $y,z \in k$ can be arbitrary and still $f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. If $f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, then by the first coordinate, $x=0$ and the rest does not matter so in particular the preimage of $(0,0,0)$ is the set $\{(x,y,z) \colon x=0, y,z \in k\}$.

Comment: @RobArthan Zariski, I should probably write $\mathbb{A}_k^3$ for $k^3$.

Answer (score 3):

Let  $(a,b,c)$ in $f(k^3)$, then , ther exists $(x,y,z)\in k^3$ such that:

$$a=x,b=xy,c=xyz$$
If $a\neq 0$  and  $b \neq 0$ then:
$$x=a, y=\frac ba, z=\frac cb$$

If $a=0$   then $x=0$ and $b=0$  and  $c=0$ . Thus $a=b=c=0$

If $b=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$ Thus: $b=c=0$

That shows that (whre $k^*=k\backslash\{0\}$): $$f(k^3)=(k^*\times k^*\times k) \cup (k\times\{0\}\times\{0\}) $$ and forall $(a,b,c)\in k^3$, we have :

$f(a,0,0)=(a,0,0)$ and if   $ab\neq 0$, then: $f(a,\frac ba, \frac cb)=(a,b,c)$